# Manage BBDD active sessions Spring MVC + Hibernate + Hikari

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hikaricp

With a Web Service development in Java running in a JBoss 7, I experience a weird error managing pool sessions on BBDD.

I am using a Hikari component linked to Hibernate 4 and Spring in order to manage BBDD connections, exactly in ORACLE.

Here it is the configuration:

```
public DataSource dataSourceOracle() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDataSourceClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
    config.setMinimumIdle(5);
    config.addDataSourceProperty("jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXXX:1521:XXXXXXXXX");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("XXXXXXXXXX");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("XXXXXXXXXX");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("user");
    config.addDataSourceProperty("password");
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}
```

You can check I setup maximun pool size to 20 and minimun idle is 5.

So when the WS is running and receive a load test with a lots of requests (I am using soapUI for this purposes), on BBDD is already created 20 inactive sessions, but after a while this only uses 10 sessions as you can check on this snapshot:

[image]

Never is used more than 10, in spite of having 10 inactive more and frequently it generates the following error:

```
Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryTimeoutException: Could not open connection
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:544) [spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:463) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644) [spring-aop-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
```

This is RootConfig.java which includes all configuration:

```
package com.xxxx.mpo.ws.config;

import com.xxxx.mpo.data.amasis.ws.AmasisWebService;
import com.yyyy.zzzz.mpo.thirdparty.service.ws.intr.AenaService;
import com.yyyy.zzzz.mpo.thirdparty.service.ws.intr.KeopsService;
import com.yyyy.zzzz.mpo.thirdparty.service.ws.intr.SigmaService;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws22.EndpointImpl;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 * Clase de configuración de los servicios web que se despliegan en este war
 *
 * @author 
 */
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "config.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
 "com.xxxx.mpo.data.amasis",
 "com.xxxx.mpo.ws.config",
 "com.yyyy.zzzz.mpo.thirdparty"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.xxxx.mpo.data.amasis.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ImportResource({
 "classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml",
 "classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"
})
public class RootConfig {

 // Inyectar el entorno de Spring para poder leer las propiedades
 @Autowired
 private Environment env;

 // Inyectar bus usado para desplegar los servicios web
 @Autowired
 private Bus cxfBus;

 /**
  * Configurar el endpoint del WS para acceder a Amasis
  * @param amasisWebService Implementación del WS de Amasis
  * @return 
  */
 @Bean(name = "amasisWebServiceEndpoint")
 @Autowired
 public Endpoint amasisWebServiceEndpoint(AmasisWebService amasisWebService) {
  EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, amasisWebService);
  endpoint.publish(env.getProperty("ws.amasis.publishUrl"));
  return endpoint;
 }

 /**
  * Configurar el endpoint del WS para acceder a Keops
  * @param keopsService Implementación del WS de Keops
  * @return 
  */
 @Bean(name = "keopsWebServiceEndpoint")
 @Autowired
 public Endpoint keopsWebServiceEndpoint(KeopsService keopsService) {
  EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, keopsService);
  endpoint.publish(env.getProperty("ws.keops.publishUrl"));
  return endpoint;
 }

 /**
  * Configurar el endpoint del WS para acceder al FTP de Aena
  * @param aenaService Implementación del WS de Aena
  * @return 
  */
 @Bean(name = "aenaWebServiceEndpoint")
 @Autowired
 public Endpoint aenaWebServiceEndpoint(AenaService aenaService) {
  EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, aenaService);
  endpoint.publish(env.getProperty("ws.aena.publishUrl"));
  return endpoint;
 }

 /**
  * Configurar el endpoint del WS para acceder a Sigma
  * @param sigmaService Implementacion del WS de Sigma
  * @return 
  */
 @Bean(name = "sigmaWebServiceEndpoint")
 @Autowired
 public Endpoint sigmaWebServiceEndpoint(SigmaService sigmaService) {
  EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, sigmaService);
  endpoint.publish(env.getProperty("ws.sigma.publishUrl"));
  return endpoint;
 }

 /**
  * Configuración del DataSource para conectarse a Amasis
  *
  * @return DataSource
  */
 @Bean
 @Primary
 public DataSource dataSource() {
  HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
  config.setDataSourceClassName(env.getProperty("datasource.amasis.driver"));
  //config.addDataSourceProperty("url", env.getProperty("datasource.amasis.url"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", env.getProperty("datasource.amasis.host"));
  //config.addDataSourceProperty("portNumber ", env.getProperty("datasource.amasis.port"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", env.getProperty("datasource.amasis.database"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("user", env.getProperty("datasource.amasis.user"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("password", env.getProperty("datasource.amasis.password"));
  config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1");
  return new HikariDataSource(config);
 }

 /**
  * Configuración del DataSource para conectarse a la DB de Aims(oracle)
  * @return DataSourceOracle
  */
 @Bean(name = "dataSourceOracle")
 public DataSource dataSourceOracle() {
  HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
  config.setDataSourceClassName(env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.driver"));
  config.setMaximumPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.maximumPoolSize")));
  config.setMaxLifetime(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.maxLifetime")));
  config.setIdleTimeout(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.idleTimeout")));
  config.setMinimumIdle(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.minimumIdle")));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("url", env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.url"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.host"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.database"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("user", env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.user"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("password", env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.password"));
  //config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.cachePrepStmts"));
  //config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.prepStmtCacheSize"));
  //config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", env.getProperty("datasource.oracle.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit"));
  return new HikariDataSource(config);
 }

 /**
  * Configuración del DataSource para conectarse a la DB de MPO
  * @return DataSource
  */
 @Bean(name = "dataSourceMPO")
 public DataSource dataSourceMPO() {
  HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
  config.setDataSourceClassName(env.getProperty("datasource.mpo.driver"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("url", env.getProperty("datasource.mpo.url"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("user", env.getProperty("datasource.mpo.user"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("password", env.getProperty("datasource.mpo.password"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", env.getProperty("datasource.mpo.cachePrepStmts"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", env.getProperty("datasource.mpo.prepStmtCacheSize"));
  config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", env.getProperty("datasource.mpo.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit"));
  return new HikariDataSource(config);
 }

 /**
  * Crear propiedades de hibernate leyendo de las propiedades para un
  * datasource específico
  *
  * @param dataSource Nombre del datasource
  * @return Propiedades de hibernate
  */
 private Properties sessionFactoryProperties(String dataSource) {
  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("datasource." + dataSource + ".hibernate.dialect"));
  properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("datasource." + dataSource + ".hibernate.showSql"));
  properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("datasource." + dataSource + ".hibernate.hbm2ddl"));
  /*properties.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", env.getProperty("datasource." + dataSource + ".hibernate.autocommit"));
   properties.put("hibernate.transaction.factory_class", env.getProperty("datasource." + dataSource + ".hibernate.factoryClass"));*/
  return properties;
 }

 /**
  * Configuración del Session factory utilizado para conectarse a Amasis
  *
  * @return
  */
 @Bean
 @Primary
 public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
  LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
  sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
  sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty("datasource.amasis.packagesToScan"));
  sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(sessionFactoryProperties("amasis"));
  return sessionFactoryBean;
 }

 /**
  * Configuración del Session factory utilizado para conectarse a Aims
  *
  * @return
  */
 @Bean
 public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryAims() {
  LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
  sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSourceOracle());
  //sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty("datasource.amasis.packagesToScan"));
  sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(sessionFactoryProperties("aims"));
  return sessionFactoryBean;
 }

 /**
  * Configuración del Session Factory utilizado para conectarse a MPO
  * @return Instancia del Session Factory
  */
 @Bean(name = "sessionFactoryMPO")
 public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryMPO() {
  LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
  sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSourceMPO());
  sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty("datasource.mpo.packagesToScan"));
  sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(sessionFactoryProperties("mpo"));
  return sessionFactoryBean;
 }


 /**
  * Configuración del transaction manager
  * @param sessionFactory Session factory
  * @return Instancia del transaction manager
  */
 @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
 @Primary
 @Autowired
 public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

  HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
  transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
  transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
  return transactionManager;
 }

 /**
  * Configuración del transaction manager Aims (oracle)
  * @param sessionFactory Session factory
  * @return Instancia del transaction manager Aims
  */
 @Bean(name = "transactionManagerOracle")
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactoryAims")
 public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManagerOracle(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

  HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
  transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
  transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSourceOracle());
  return transactionManager;
 }

 /**
  * Configuración del transaction manager de MPO
  * @param sessionFactory Session factory
  * @return Instancia del transaction manager
  */
 @Bean(name = "transactionManagerMPO")
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactoryMPO")
 public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManagerMPO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

  HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
  transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
  transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSourceMPO());
  return transactionManager;
 }

 /**
  * Configuración del jdbc template
  *
  * @return Instancia del jdbc template
  */
 @Bean
 public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
  return jdbcTemplate;
 }

 /**
  * Configurar EntityManagerFactory
  * @return Instancia de EntityManagerFactory
  */
 @Bean
 @Primary
 public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
  HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
  vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
  factory.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty("datasource.amasis.packagesToScan"));
  factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
  factory.afterPropertiesSet();
  return factory.getObject();
 }

 /**
  * Configurar EntityManagerFactory de MPO
  *
  * @return Instancia de EntityManagerFactory
  */
 @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryMPO")
 public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryMPO() {

  HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
  vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

  LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
  factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
  factory.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty("datasource.mpo.packagesToScan"));
  factory.setDataSource(dataSourceMPO());
  factory.afterPropertiesSet();

  return factory.getObject();
 }

 /**
  * Configurar origen de las propiedades
  * @return Instancia de PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
  */
 @Bean
 public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
  PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
  propertyConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("com/yyyy/zzzz/mpo/ws/config.properties"));
  return propertyConfigurer;
 }
}
```

Please, could you help me how to use this 10 more sessions and avoid these errors?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Add your hibernate configuration, transaction configuration only dumping a stack trace and a datasource configuration isn't going to help. Generally those issues are due to wrong transaction configuration or messing around with connections yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum, hibernate and transaction configuration is include all in a java class:

Comment: I have included it on the description.

Comment: You don't accidentily have `hibernate.properties` or `hibernate.cfg.xml`.  Also your `@EnableTransactionManager` will only use the default `transactionManager` for trnasactions. For others you need to add `@Transactional("name-of-tx-manager")` to the services/methods. Next to that you are also using JPA but fail to setup transaction managers for those, so if you use multiple resources in a single transactions things will break apart quite quickly.